# JSS Setup script failing with: Assertion `args[1]->IsInt32()' failed

Tags: jss

Following the [JSS quick start instructions](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/quick-start) I do:

```
npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
jss create my-first-jss-app react
cd my-first-jss-app
jss start
```

Next step I go to is to run `JSS Setup` before this I have gone through all prerequisite steps shown on the [JSS Server Setup](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install) page.

1. Installed Server Components
2. Verified server components installed and worked by visiting `http://your-sitecore-instance/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=TEST`

Now I go into my newly created app folder for `my-first-jss-app`. Within this I load up a bash CLI in admin mode I run `jss setup`. To get:

```
npm[30856]: src\node_file.cc:1599: Assertion `args[1]->IsInt32()' failed.
 1: 00007FF776FA0EFA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4810
 2: 00007FF776F7A296 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 00007FF776F7A34F node::MakeCallback+4703
 4: 00007FF776F3F413 uv_loop_fork+34643
 5: 00007FF7777AADD2 v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+60562
 6: 00007FF7777AC26D v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+65837
 7: 00007FF7777AB2C9 v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+61833
 8: 00007FF7777AB1AB v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+61547
 9: 000003BD8BBDC5C1
```

Why is this going wrong?

Debugging this I confirm the following:-

- CLI is in admin mode
- Node version: v10.15.1
- NPM version: 6.4.1
- JSS version: 11.0.2
- Using `nvm` to manage version of node used
- Unable to so far get verbose logs
- Removing lock file and node modules folder and running `npm install` doesn't fix the issue

Using `nvm` to install and change to second version of Node. In my case `8.15.0` produces a different result worth mentioning. `jss setup` just hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple steps to try, some I have mentioned in the question. If you run in the similar issues I recommend doing the following to help get to bottom of it.

- Use a tool like `nvm` to help switch between versions of node and npm module on your machine quickly and easily.
- Try node at x64 and x86 bit architecture
- Try different versions of node and npm
- At your own risk, delete node_modules folder and/or remove package.json.lock file in your created app folder and hit `npm install`
- Try it out on a different machine

However before you do any of the above, I recommend trying a different CLI.

- `Git Bash` CLI was the culprit here, why I do not know.
- I moved over to `powershell` CLI it worked I now however gone back to another old favorite of mine `cmder` where it works just fine as well.